# tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage45" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to import a python module `yt.py` having image labels and buttons to a python file `fpassm.py` which have a image button when it is clicked, but it gives me a error
`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage45" doesn't exist`.

```
ytphoto=PhotoImage(file='youtube.png')
yt=Button(root,image=ytphoto,borderwidth=0, activebackground='#ffffff', command = youtube)
ytsize=ytphoto.subsample(1,1)
yt.config(image=ytsize,bg='#fdffff')
yt.place(x = 300,y = 100)
```

Comment: where is rest of the code? create minimal working code which we could run. If you create PhotoImage in function then maybe you have problem with bug which removes PhotoImage when it is assigned to local variable.

Comment: **If** this code is inside a function, then the image assigned to `ytphoto` is a local variable which will be destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: I believe this error can also happen, if you have more than one instance of `Tk()` and your assigning to a different instance